# How to assign value to javascript variable in django

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I was trying to assign value to a javascript variable in django. I need the value of javascript variable like.

```
var chartData = [{
                section: "Czech Republic",
                attempted: 301.90
            }, {
                section: "Ireland",
                attempted: 201.10
            }];
```

In my django view I am using the following code to generate and render the json data.

```
i = 0
    chart1Data = []
    while(i<len(totalSectionsJson)):
        chart1Data.append({'section':totalSectionsJson[i].encode('utf8'),'attempted':sectionTotalAttempted[i]})
        i = i+1
    chart1DataExport = json.dumps(chart1Data)
```

In the template I am using `var chartData = {{chart1Data|safe}};` to assign the javascript variable. But I am getting the data like

```
var chartData = [{"attempted": 0, "section": "section"}, {"attempted": 0, "section": "section2"}, {"attempted": 0, "section": "section3"}];
```

I need to eliminate the quotes from `attempted` and `section`. How can I do that?

Comment: You'd better do the conversion in `js` like `var chartData = [conversion for x in chart1Data]`(sorry not familiar with js grammar), hope this help

Comment: Why do you need to eliminate the quotes? Json requires them, javascript doesn't care.

Comment: Alternatively, pass `chart1DataExport` as a string literal and use JSON.parse in your javascript code.

Comment: @knbk can you please explain a bit more